# No response from a Flask application using Apache server

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I have created a flask application and am hosting it on a Ubuntu server.  I know that my apache config is correct since I am able serve the example flask application.  However, this one seems to be giving me trouble.  The code is below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
import pickle
import engine
import config

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


model = pickle.load(open(config.MODEL_PATH, "rb"))
collection = engine.Collection(config.DATABASE_PATH)
search_engine = engine.SearchEngine(model, collection)


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/search/', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    query = request.form['query']
    results = search_engine.query(query)
    return render_template('form_action.html', query=query, results=results)


@app.route('/retrieve/<int:item_number>', methods=['GET'])
def retrieve(item_number):
    item = engine.Product(item_number, collection.open_document(str(item_number)))
    return render_template('document.html', item=item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

When running the file directly through the python interpreter, it works fine and I can access.  However, when starting through apache and wsgi, I get no response from the server.  It just hangs when making a request and nothing is available on the logs.

I suspect that my issue may have something to do with the three objects I initialize at the beginning of the program.  Perhaps it gets stuck running those?

Update: I have tried commenting out certain parts of the code to see what is causing it to stall.  Tracing it out to the engine module, importing NearestNeighbors seems to be causing the issue.

```
import sqlite3
import config
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from preprocessor import preprocess_document
from collections import namedtuple
```

Comment: _I suspect that my issue may have something to do with the three objects I initialize at the beginning of the program_ Have you tried commenting those out, and then seeing if the `/` URL works?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried commenting out different parts of it.  It looks like importing the engine module is causing the issue.  However, commenting that out and leaving the pickle.load uncommented also causes it to stall.